# DotNetZip trouble with russian encoding

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetzip

i use DotNetZip in my project.

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile()) 
{ 
   zip.ProvisionalAlternateEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(866); 
   zip.AddFile(filename, "directory\\in\\archive"); 
   zip.Save("archive.zip"); 
}
```

all ok but when i use method AddDirectoryByName i have a bad directory names.

Comment: Is there any particular ZIP library you are using?

Comment: What do you mean by "bad name"?  Can you post a specific example?

Comment: I've tried it with the newest DotNetZip version and do not get an exception: `using (var zip = new ZipFile()) { zip.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866); zip.AddDirectoryByName("Россия"); zip.Save("archive.zip"); }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Universal way for all is :**

```
zip.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
zip.ProvisionalAlternateEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(Console.OutputEncoding.CodePage);
zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
```

Answer (score 5):

This way in new version work for me

```
zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.Always;
zip.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
```

Answer (score 3):

You may Peek Definition first.
Then you will find this:

```
public ZipFile(Encoding encoding);
```

So you can use this:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(Encoding.UTF8))
```